# Google colab blocking requests.get, causing 403 error

Tags: python, python-requests, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to scrape web reviews from the appstore through rss and when I run my code on a local environment, it runs just fine and it gets all the requests 200 without issue. but if i run my code in google colab, it eventually fails after a while and google seems to block it, giving a 403 error.

i've tried adding headers, putting a time sleep, and adding a proxy to the request but nothing seems to work.

does anyone know how to fix this? thank you very much.

Here is a link to an example of my code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gVCpIA3t0h05lPo670hp5i9jZxXRnsN9?usp=sharing

The following below is a simplified version of my code

````
import re
import glob
import requests
import time

countries = ["us", "dz", "ao", "ai", "ag"]

# proxy. get one from https://spys.one/en/ of type HTTP (not HTTPS)
proxy = {
    # "https": 'http://95.154.76.20:3128 ',
    "http": 'http://66.11.117.253:9999' 
}

failed_try = 0

def requesturl(url):
  global failed_try
  global proxy

  headers = {
      'User-Agent': ('Mozilla/6.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) '
                    'Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'),
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }

  while True:
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxy)
    if response.status_code == 403:
      print(response, "  Retrying request...")
      failed_try += 1
      if failed_try >= 5:
        time.sleep(2)
      continue
    failed_try = 0
    return response


# downloads reviews by county
def download(country):
  global total_review_count
  # list of target genres
  genres = {
    "action": "7001",
    "strategy": "7017",
    "sports": "7016",
  }
  
  # shows current country progress
  country_pos = f"{countries.index(country)+1}/{len(countries)}"
  print(f"\n\n\n================Scraping Country {country_pos}================")
  
  # iterate through mode of payment
  for payment in ["topfreeapplications", "toppaidapplications"]:
    print(f"\n\n================Scraping {payment} [{country_pos}]================")
    # loop through every genre
    for genre in genres:
      print(f"\n     Getting {genre} list...")
      # get list of games per genre and type of payment
      genre_link = f"https://itunes.apple.com/{country}/rss/{payment}/limit=200/genre={genres[genre]}/json"
      
      dict_genre_resp = requesturl(genre_link)
      print("this>", dict_genre_resp, genre_link)
      dict_genre_response = dict_genre_resp.json()
      
      # number o
      review_count = 0

      # iterates through every game in a genre  
      for game in dict_genre_response["feed"]["entry"]:
        # get relevant data from response
        game_id = game["id"]["attributes"]["im:id"]
        game_name = game["title"]['label']

        # Loop through the game's reviews per pages
        for n in range(1,10+1):
          # get review 

          reviews_response = requesturl(f"https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/page={n}/id={game_id}/sortBy=mostRecent/json")
          print(game_name, reviews_response)
        print()



def main():
  for country in countries:
    download(country)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()```
````

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same error. This may not be a perfect solution, but it works. Google caches websites frequently, so you can use the cached website to scrape.
Modify your URL `http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:<your url>`
This only works for static webpages.